# How can two parse apps share PFObjects and link identities via PFUser?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I have an iPad-only app where some users (the ones who buy in-app purchases) have PFUser objects that are linked to their currentInstallation like this:

```
PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
if( [PFUser currentUser] != nil )
    currentInstallation[@"user"] = [PFUser currentUser];
```

The identity behind the PFUser is the Facebook identity:

```
        [PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebook];
        [PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:nil block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
            if (!user) {
                // Handle error path
                failPath();

            } else {
                // Handle success path
                [FBRequestConnection startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {

                    if (error) {
                        failPath();

                    } else {
                        // Save the name on Parse
                        [PFUser currentUser][kParseUserKeyFacebookName] = user.name;
                        [PFUser currentUser][kParseUserKeyFacebookID] = user.objectID;
                        [[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackgroundWithBlock:....
```

Now I want to release a new app for the iPhone, which acts as a kind of "admin console" for the iPad app. The iPhone app will receive push notifications when things go wrong on the iPad app etc (the iPad is in use by many people).

**Question**: On the new iPhone app, presuming I can get the user to log in with the same facebook ID, how can I correlate back to the same user's ipad data on parse? For example can I get the ipad app's PFObjects and/or PFUser data in the iphone now?

Concrete example: set a password on the ipad app, log into facebook on the iphone app, enter that same password. How to check it against the ipad app password, from the iphone?

Comment: Maybe create a new PFUser object that would represent the Admin user on the iPhone, and save the iPhone installation configuration in there. connect the iPad PFUser and the iPhone PFUser in a join table.

Both PFUsers would have the same Facebook identity.
I haven't done this, but thus is just an idea.

Comment: How would you do this part: "connect the iPad PFUser and the iPhone PFUser in a join table" ... is that some parse cloud code thing?